# Dokku running on ubuntu, asking for password on git push

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, dokku

I recently installed dokku on a Ubuntu 16.04.4 box, and things worked normally for a while.

After I configured a website on nginx outside of dokku (manually editing `/etc/nginx/sites-available`), my deployment stopped working, asking for password for the dokku user (that was passwordless before).
Searching around, I thought the problem could be with my ssh key, so I tried:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@netunia.tk dokku ssh-keys:add admin
```

I also checked in `/home/dokku/.ssh/authorized_keys` and my key is present there.
I'm lost, even thinking on backuping and rebuilding my box from scratch.

Comment: Does the output of `ssh -vv dokku@netunia.tk` shows it its trying to use your keys? Which are the permissions of your `.ssh` directories? Does server's sshd logs show anything about authentication attemps?

Comment: I'n not familiar with debugging ssh, but the output seems to indicate it tries two keys, one of which is in `authorized_keys`. The output of `ls -l /home/dokku/.ssh` is `-rw-r--r-- 1 dokku root 1632 Jan  5 18:35 authorized_keys`. sshd logs show failures for user root, and this: `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/dokku/.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

Following tips (thanks [@Gonzalo Matheu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520275/gonzalo-matheu)) I checked the server sshd logs and found the following:

`Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/dokku/.ssh`

I changed the permissions on dokku's ssh directory using the following, and it's working (passwordless) again!

```
chmod 700 /home/dokku/.ssh  
chmod 600 /home/dokku/.ssh/authorized_keys
```